# Solr/Lucene update query deletes attribute from data

Tags: json, solr, lucene

I am running into an issue with an attribute missing in the data after running an update query.

I run a select query like this:

curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/select?q=title%3AHans+head:true&fl=title,uid,articleId,missing_Attribute,my_otherAttribute&wt=json&indent=true"

It returns an article:

```
{ 
"title":"Hans", 
"uid":"18_UNIQUEID_123", 
"articleId":"123123123", 
"missing_Attribute":"M",
}
```

So missing_Attribute = M, my_otherAttribute is not present yet. Which is fine.

Then I run an update query on this document using:
curl http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/update?commit=true --data-binary @MyUpdate.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'

with MyUpdate.json as:

```
[
  {
    "uid": "18_UNIQUEID_123",
    "my_otherAttribute": {
      "set": "12"
    }
  }
]
```

And run the select query again, results in:

```
{ 
"title":"Hans", 
"uid":"18_UNIQUEID_123", 
"articleId":"123123123", 
"my_otherAttribute":"12",
}
```

my_otherAttribute = 12 *but missing_Attribute is gone*!

Why is missing_Attribute gone when I update my_otherAttribute?

Why does it not affect any of the other fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the answer is:
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates

The issue I face is that I want to make a partial update of a document. I am using Solr 4.10, so in theory it would work. But only if the schema would support it. And ours does not. So that is why attributes disappear.